# Labels in Google geomap API

Tags: javascript, google-geocoding-api, google-visualization

I am working on this code at the moment, it all works well but when I hover a country with my mouse I only want the country name to appear in the label, not the related value. Can I do that? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the javascript code:

```
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Value'],
      ['Albania', 1],
      ['Algeria', 1],
    ]);

    var options = {
        colorAxis: {colors:['#386a90']}, legend:'none', datalessRegionColor:'#f1f1f1'
        };
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that.
You can avoid the tooltip altogether with this [option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Configuration_Options):

```
tooltip: {trigger: 'none'}
```

Otherwise, but this is not supported by the API, you could probably manage to avoid the display of the strings "Value", ":" and "1" by looking for - with jQuery.contains() for example - all the tags of type "text" that contain the strings "Value", ":" or "1" and hide them. This is not going to look very nice because the tooltip square is going to stay large, but this may do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extra tooltip field and add the data that way.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data.addColumn('string', 'Country'); 
data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'}); 

data.addRows([['Albania',1,"Extra Information"]]);
data.addRows([['Algeria',1,"Extra Information"]]);
```

I used this code format in my app: 
http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/france-example/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to work when using an array to create the datatable, but works if you directly create a data table and populate it with entries. Explained here: [How to remove coordinates from tooltip of Googles Geo Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414966/how-to-remove-coordinates-from-tooltip-of-googles-geo-charts)