# How to remove coordinates from tooltip of Googles Geo Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I've added some markers to my map (using Googles Chart API)

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Lat');
data.addColumn('number', 'Long');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'}); 

data.addRows([
    [48.1667,14.0333, 15, 'Tooltiptext'],
    [48.2000,14.0333, 25, 'Tooltiptext'],
    [48.2000,14.2333, 35, 'Tooltiptext']
]);
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the lat/long and replace it with `Tooltiptext: {value}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this data structure, for example:

```
google.visualization.DataTable();

 data.addColumn('number', 'Lat');                                
 data.addColumn('number', 'Long');
 data.addColumn('string','tooltip');
 data.addColumn('number','Example');
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});

data.addRows([[41.151636,-8.569336,'Portugal',0,'test PT']]);
data.addRows([[ 39.059575,-98.789062,'USA',1,'test US']]);
```

This way the coordinates wont show up, and you'll have 2 lines for the tooltip.

Check a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmoreira/q9Jzz/

Comment: I just found exact that example, thanks! I even have bought your map creator on CC just to find that info :)

Comment: Nice! Glad I was able to help! It's a small world the internet - I use your amazing Statementer :)

Comment: Cool, This is how I implement it: https://twitter.com/revaxarts/status/271285097175609345/